# axios get request in reactJS

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, get-request

I am new to the react and I am learning how to HTTP get request using axios. I am referring to a youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NEYrSUM4Umw and following along, but I got an error. I think I have minor error but I can't figure it out.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

class PostList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
             posts: []
        }
    }


    componentDidMount(){

        axios.get('https://api.particle.io/v1/devices/64646468431646/temperature?access_token=547376a1b2')

        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            this.setState({posts: response.data})
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        }
        )
    }

    render() {
        const { posts } = this.state
        return (
            <div>
                temperature
                {
                    posts.length ?
                    posts.map(post => <div key={post.coreInfo.deviceID}> {post.result} </div>) :
                    null
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default PostList
```

When I use postman to get a HTTP request, I get the following response:

> {
>       "cmd": "VarReturn",
>       "name": "temperature",
>       "result": "67.55",
>       "coreInfo": {
>           "last_app": "",
>           "last_heard": "2020-04-05",
>           "connected": true,
>           "last_handshake_at": "2020-04-05",
>           "deviceID": "64646468431646",
>           "product_id": 8
>       } }

My goal is to display the result: 67.55 in the web application.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only getting a single object as the response from your fetch instead of an array, just wrap it in an array -

```
this.setState({posts: [response.data]})
```